Installing libpng gets error: C compiler cannot create executables
I'm currently trying to install pokefirered for ROM-Hacking following the INSTALL.md file in the repository. I've already install devKitPro and msys2 and am currently trying to install libpng. I ran the included commands:
tar xf libpng-1.6.37.tar.xz
cd libpng-1.6.37
./configure --prefix=/usr
make check
make install

but I get an error after ./configure --prefix=/usr:
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
configure: loading site script /etc/config.site
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/thepe/Downloads/libpng-1.6.37':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Here is the config file for debugging details:
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libpng configure 1.6.37, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = DESKTOP-U760G6B
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.4.10.x86_64
uname -s = MSYS_NT-10.0-22631
uname -v = 2024-04-08 18:11 UTC

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /opt/devkitpro/tools/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /opt/bin
PATH: /c/Windows/System32
PATH: /c/Windows
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /usr/bin/site_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/vendor_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/core_perl


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2209: loading site script /etc/config.site
| # This file is in public domain.
| # Original author: Karlson2k (Evgeny Grin)
| # Written for MSys2 to help running 'configure' scripts
| 
| # Defaults for MSys2/MinGW64-targeted programs
| 
| # Set proper selfname on bash and fallback to default name on other shells
| test -n "${BASH_SOURCE}" 2>/dev/null && config_site_me="${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/}" || config_site_me=config.site
| 
| # Set default 'host' to speedup configure
| if test -z "$build_alias"; then
|   build_alias="${MSYSTEM_CHOST}"  && \
|     ${as_echo-echo} "$config_site_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: default build_alias set to $build_alias" >&5
| fi
| 
| # Set default 'prefix'
| if ( test -z "$prefix" || test "x$prefix" = "xNONE" ) && \
|     ( test -z "$exec_prefix" || test "x$exec_prefix" = "xNONE" ); then
|   prefix="${MSYSTEM_PREFIX}" && \
|     ${as_echo-echo} "$config_site_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: default prefix set to $prefix" >&5
| fi
config.site:13: default build_alias set to x86_64-pc-msys
configure:2358: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2426: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2437: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2492: result: yes
configure:2643: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2682: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:2689: checking for gawk
configure:2705: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2716: result: gawk
configure:2727: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2749: result: yes
configure:2778: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2795: result: yes
configure:2925: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2934: result: no
configure:3014: checking for gcc
configure:3030: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3041: result: gcc
configure:3270: checking for C compiler version
configure:3279: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3290: $? = 0
configure:3279: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-msys
Configured with: /c/S/B/src/gcc-13.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-msys --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --enable-languages=c,c++,lto --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-isl-version-check --enable-checking=release --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 13.2.0 (GCC) 
configure:3290: $? = 0
configure:3279: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3290: $? = 1
configure:3279: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3290: $? = 1
configure:3310: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3332: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault signal terminated program cc1
Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source (by using -freport-bug).
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
configure:3336: $? = 4
configure:3374: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libpng"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libpng"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.6.37"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libpng 1.6.37"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "png-mng-implement@lists.sourceforge.net"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libpng"
| #define VERSION "1.6.37"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3379: error: in `/home/thepe/Downloads/libpng-1.6.37':
configure:3381: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PNG_COPTS_set=
ac_cv_env_PNG_COPTS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/thepe/Downloads/libpng-1.6.37/missing aclocal-1.16'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/thepe/Downloads/libpng-1.6.37/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/thepe/Downloads/libpng-1.6.37/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/thepe/Downloads/libpng-1.6.37/missing automake-1.16'
AWK='gawk'
CC='gcc'
CCAS=''
CCASDEPMODE=''
CCASFLAGS=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='cygpath -w'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DFNCPP=''
DLLTOOL=''
DO_INSTALL_LIBPNG_CONFIG_FALSE=''
DO_INSTALL_LIBPNG_CONFIG_TRUE=''
DO_INSTALL_LIBPNG_PC_FALSE=''
DO_INSTALL_LIBPNG_PC_TRUE=''
DO_INSTALL_LINKS_FALSE=''
DO_INSTALL_LINKS_TRUE=''
DO_PNG_PREFIX_FALSE=''
DO_PNG_PREFIX_TRUE=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME_FALSE=''
HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME_TRUE=''
HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT_FALSE=''
HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT_TRUE=''
HAVE_SOLARIS_LD_FALSE=''
HAVE_SOLARIS_LD_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/thepe/Downloads/libpng-1.6.37/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='libpng'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='png-mng-implement@lists.sourceforge.net'
PACKAGE_NAME='libpng'
PACKAGE_STRING='libpng 1.6.37'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libpng'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.6.37'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PNGLIB_MAJOR='1'
PNGLIB_MINOR='6'
PNGLIB_RELEASE='37'
PNGLIB_VERSION='1.6.37'
PNG_ARM_NEON_FALSE=''
PNG_ARM_NEON_TRUE=''
PNG_COPTS=''
PNG_INTEL_SSE_FALSE=''
PNG_INTEL_SSE_TRUE=''
PNG_MIPS_MSA_FALSE=''
PNG_MIPS_MSA_TRUE=''
PNG_POWERPC_VSX_FALSE=''
PNG_POWERPC_VSX_TRUE=''
PNG_PREFIX=''
POW_LIB=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
VERSION='1.6.37'
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
binconfigs=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias='x86_64-pc-msys'
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/thepe/Downloads/libpng-1.6.37/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgconfigdir=''
prefix='/usr'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "libpng"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libpng"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.6.37"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libpng 1.6.37"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "png-mng-implement@lists.sourceforge.net"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "libpng"
#define VERSION "1.6.37"

configure: exit 77

I've already tried checking my current GCC installation that I already installed on my computer before download MSYS2 and devKitPro, but I still cant find the problem.

BTW, I'm in Windows

You're running this inside MSYS2 terminal, right?

Yes, I'm using the bash msys2 in devkitarm/msys2

Why not just install the libpng package provided by the MSYS2 package manager?    pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-libpng

Usually, "C compiler cannot create executables" is a red herring, with the actual issue having to do with compilation flags, or filesystem issues, or whatever.  In your case, however, the compiler genuinely crashed while trying to build a trivial test program.  This is likely an issue with your iinstallation of the compiler, and you should be able to reproduce it directly.  But it's going to be very difficult for anyone on this side of the screen to tell you what's wrong on your side.

What gcc is installed, and why are you not using the one provided by msys2?

I used C before trying to ROM hack

Uninstall GCC, all of them. Install GCC from the MSYS2 package manager.
